# Sending Multiple data to PHP page without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery

Please I am new to jQuery so i just copied the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Type here and press Enter">
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#name').keypress(function(event) {
            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var info = $('#name').val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "action.php",
                    data: {name: info},
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#name').val('');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the php code:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo '<h1>'.$_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

Its Working perfectly but now i want to have more than one input field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" >
<input type="text" id="job">
```

but i don't know how to run the jQuery code for the 2 input fields so that it can transfer them to the php page. Please i need help

Comment: I would suggest trying to understand the code that you have copied. Then you will see how easy this is. :-)

Comment: I'm assuming this is just for testing purposes, but you should never echo user-supplied data without sanitizing it first (e.g. `htmlentities()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple values using `data` param of ajax request like this.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        job: $('#job').val()
    },
    success: function(status) {
        $('#result').append(status);

        $('#name, #job').val(''); // Reset value of both fields
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code with some addition in html and JS.
Wrap your inputs in `form` tag. and add a preventDefault on submit.
Use  jQuery [**.serialize()**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method 
and [**event.preventDefault()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

- `event.preventDefault()` :  If this method is called, the default
  action of the event will not be triggered. (it will prevent page
  reload / redirection) to any page.
- `.serialize()` : Encode a set of form elements as a string for
  submission.

**serialized string output will be like `key=value` pair with `&` separated. :**

`name=john&job=developer.....`

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Type here and press submit">
  <input type="text" id="job" placeholder="Type here and press submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                var serialized = $('#myform').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "action.php",
                    data: serialized,
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#myform').reset();
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```